# Jersey/JAX-RS client throwing exception on HTTP GET

Tags: rest, groovy, jersey, jax-rs

**Please note**: even though I'm using Groovy here, I think my exception is really about using the Jersey/JAX-RS API correctly.

Given the following code:

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig()
clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE)
Client jerseyClient = Client.create(clientConfig)
WebResource webResource = jerseyClient.resource("http://localhost:8080/location/")

Long id = 5L

Address address = webResource.path("address").path(id)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .get(Long)
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.path() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Long) values: [5]
Possible solutions: path(java.lang.String), put(), wait(long), put(com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType), put(java.lang.Class), put(java.lang.Object)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:55)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at com.me.myapp.Driver.run(Driver.groovy:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    <rest omitted for brevity>
```

I am trying to hit the following REST endpoint:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/location/address/{id}
```

**Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Jeff Storey is correct (+1). If you are concerned about the server side, meaning you are expecting a Long, you don't need to worry, as the String path segment will get converted to a Long, as long as it is the correct format.

Comment: Sorry @peeskillet (+1) - I posted bad code; please see my update, does that change anything in your mind? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't see anything changed from before, except the value in the exception. Message is the same. As Jeff Storey said, `.path` should take a String. So just do `.path(id.ToString())`

Comment: Also I'm very curious about `.get(Long)`. I don't know about that. It should be `.get(Address.class)` if you are expecting that type in the response

Comment: Thanks again @peeskillet (+2 for both!). I made both changes (changing `id` to String and replacing `Long` for `Address` (in Groovy you don't need to put a `.class` when specifying a class type) and now I am getting `ConnectionRefused` exceptions, which makes sense since I don't have a server (yet) listening locally on that port. Thank you! **Once last followup question:** is there a way (for logging purposes) to print out the full URL and HTTP VERB that Jersey/JAX-RS is about to call? ...

Comment: In my case it would be nice to print out something like "*Jersey is about to hit the following RESTful endpoint: GET http://localhost:8080/location/address/5.*" Is this possible to your knowledge? Thanks again!

Comment: Do some research on servlet filters. You can do pre/post processing of all requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the `path` method with a `long`, but it can only take a `String`. Your `id` is a `long`, but since the error message says the value is `1`, I assume that `LocationResourcePaths.ADDRESS_PATH` is also a `long` with value `1`, is that the case?

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Storey (+1) - but I have to apologize; I posted bad code snippets. Please see my update, does this change anything in your mind? Thanks again!